# Throttling requests based on ip

Tags: servlets, throttling, ddos

My web app runs on AWS Ec2. I am throttling requests in my servlet doPost() based on various parameters following [Protect yourself against Dos attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029380/protect-yourself-against-dos-attacks) answer.

How do I throttle requests before it gets to my servlet?

Maybe based on IP (or) based on tps at load balancer level.